# [Talos] How to play motion with the talos in gazebo

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I am using ros melodic.

whole package builds successfully with the procedure on the [ros tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TALOS/Tutorials/Installation/Simulation).

I tried to launch the [talos_gazebo.launch](https://github.com/pal-robotics/talos_simulation/blob/kinetic-devel/talos_gazebo/launch/talos_gazebo.launch), it spawns the robot successfully and robot is standing steadily at origin.

But I am getting following errors, (for detailed terminal output please refer [output.log](https://github.com/pal-robotics/talos_tutorials/files/8647279/output.log) file or [output pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rsZji0Dw))

**Error parsing urdf.** (which I think is not a major issue)

```
[ERROR] [1652021719.240644221]: Joint 'leg_right_flex_1_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021719.240756035]: Joint 'leg_right_flex_2_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021719.240862152]: Joint 'leg_left_flex_1_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021719.240949917]: Joint 'leg_left_flex_2_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021720.880122384]: Joint 'leg_right_flex_1_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021720.880262388]: Joint 'leg_right_flex_2_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021720.880360828]: Joint 'leg_left_flex_1_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
[ERROR] [1652021720.880452919]: Joint 'leg_left_flex_2_joint' marked as passive is not known to the URDF. Ignoring.
```

**Error loading controllers**

It fails to load the controllers from the [talos_moveit_config/config/controllers_full.yaml](https://github.com/pal-robotics/talos_moveit_config/blob/indigo-devel/config/controllers_full.yaml). such as `left_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory`, `right_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory` etc. I do not see other error in the output of `move_group.launch`.

```
[ERROR] [1652021876.017916518, 18.457000000]: Action client not connected: left_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ WARN] [1652021920.441594524, 23.472000000]: Waiting for right_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ WARN] [1652021973.351357007, 29.472000000]: Waiting for right_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
```

Also when I tried to play some motion using `/play_motion/goal` msg, it gives following error.

```
[ERROR] [1652023226.329640663, 194.157000000]: No controller was found for joint 'torso_1_joint'
[ERROR] [1652023226.329704845, 194.157000000]: Motion 'walk_pose' could not be played.
[ERROR] [1652023261.992356484, 198.031000000]: No controller was found for joint 'arm_left_1_joint'
[ERROR] [1652023261.992572631, 198.031000000]: Motion 'wave' could not be played.
[ERROR] [1652023283.334062512, 200.350000000]: No controller was found for joint 'head_1_joint'
[ERROR] [1652023283.334157470, 200.350000000]: Motion 'test_head' could not be played.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Also if you have any tutorial on how to get started with the talos robot or you have some path to progress quickly with talos robot simulation please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400242/%5Btalos%5D-how-to-play-motion-with-the-talos-in-gazebo./) by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2022-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Regarding your question. The error that you see about flex joints being passive and not being in the URDF don't worry about it, those are a particular set of joints available with a certain experimental parameter to the URDF. Don't worry about it, it shouldn't affect your workflow.

Regarding your issue with MoveIt, TALOS Simulation starts without any controllers. You need to started the position controllers using

> roslaunch talos_controller_configuration position_controllers.launch

This should start the position controllers on the robot and make those controllers available for MoveIt. You should now be good to use play_motion alongside.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) with karma: 228 on 2022-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-09**:
Yes it worked. Thank you very much for the quick responses!

Any suggestions/advise on how to make it walk.

Thanks again.

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2022-05-09**:
Hello,

I don't think the walking controllers are public. You can write you own controller or use any existing controllers and try to interface it to make it walk.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-09**:
Yes I will try it out. But really thank you for all your help!